# LESS CSS - Unable to divide two pixel units and return a unit-less value

Tags: css, web, less

I'd like to (*temporarily*) remove the units of my variables `@baseLineHeight` and `@baseFontSize`, so that I can divide them to get a relative `line-height`. This is what I've tried:

```
@baseFontSize: 12px;
@baseLineHeight: 18px;
font: @baseFontSize~"/"@baseLineHeight/@baseFontSize sans-serif;
```

Generates the following error:

```
Object #<Object> has no method 'toCSS' (Less::ParseError)
```

Preferred output:

```
font: 12px/1.5 sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meanwhile there seems to be a function for that:
http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-unit

Here the code from the comment, just for completeness. (thanks to cfx).

```
font: @baseFontSize~"/"unit(@baseLineHeight/@baseFontSize) sans-serif;
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Your LESS should be `font: @baseFontSize~"/"unit(@baseLineHeight/@baseFontSize) sans-serif;`

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer. I'm pretty sure my previous answer was for an older version of LESS that did not implement this method.

Answer (score 2):

I missed the part of the documentation regarding JavaScript evaluation. This seems to solve my problem:

```
font: @baseFontSize~"/"`parseInt("@{baseLineHeight}") / parseInt("@{baseFontSize}")` sans-serif;
```

Comment: @bzx 4 hours to go before I am able to :o

Comment: sorry I didn't know .. @Vague

Answer (score 1):

The other answers don't seem to actually work.

According to the [LESS documentation](http://lesscss.org), the [`unit()` function](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-unit) will remove or change the unit of a dimension. Since the function only accepts a single dimension as a parameter (and an *optional* parameter), you would use the following:

```
unit((@baseLineHeight/@baseFontSize))
```

Because of [strict math](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-strict-math), you will notice that the line above *may* need to be wrapped in parenthesis so that the math is actually evaluated.

```
@baseFontSize: 12px;
@baseLineHeight: 18px;

p {
  font: @baseFontSize ~"/" unit((@baseLineHeight/@baseFontSize)) sans-serif;
}
```

The LESS above will output the following, desired results:

```
p {
  font: 12px / 1.5 sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Well, since by default `strict-math` is off, `unit(@baseLineHeight/@baseFontSize)` will work for most (and for `sm=on` it will be `unit((@baseLineHeight/@baseFontSize))` - no need to repeat `unit` twice).

Comment: @seven-phases-max Well, I was using [this online LESS compiler](http://winless.org/online-less-compiler), and while `strict-math` is off by default, it seems like the extra parenthesis were required merely because they succeeded `~"/"` (which I presume will cause it to evaluate it as though strict math is on for that line). I went ahead and removed the redundant `unit()` function, though. Thanks for the helpful comment.

Comment: To correct myself, yes: `unit(@baseLineHeight/@baseFontSize)` won't work in `font` because this property is hardcoded to always use `sm:on`. So actually the whole statement wil then be `font: @baseFontSize / unit((@baseLineHeight/@baseFontSize)) sans-serif;` with either `sm` compiler setting. (for more details see #1627: though personally I'd treat such hardcoded properties as a language defect, since you never know which one is hardcoded and which one is not).